# How can I type a backtick on an Estonian keyboard?

Tags: keyboard

I am actually using the sweidsh keyboard with an estonian layout, so the backtick key itself produces <kbd>'</kbd> and while holding <kbd>Shift</kbd>, it produces <kbd>–</kbd>.

Is there maybe a way to create a global keyboard shortcut?

Answer (score 3):

Looking through the keybindings in the Estonian keyboard layout that ships with Mac OS X, it appears (amazingly) that the backtick character (`` ` ``) cannot be produced with any of the unmodified keys, nor with any combination of option, shift, or control, despite the fact that most of the option-character key combinations are left unmapped on this layout. There are many ways to modify it to produce this key combination.

You could create a modified Estonian layout using [Ukelele](http://scripts.sil.org/cms/scripts/page.php?site_id=nrsi&id=ukelele), you could use a program like [Keyboard Remap for Macbook](http://pqrs.org/macosx/keyremap4macbook/), or even [TextExpander](http://smilesoftware.com/TextExpander/index.html).

Comment: Thanks! I finally managed to change my keyboard layout with Ukelele. Now I can type ` with just a small keybaord shortcut!

Comment: I added my modified keyboard here: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/3573333/est%20keyb%20modified.bundle.zip . Unzip it to your home folder Library/Keyboard Layouts folder and activate/select another "Estonian" keyboard in mac preferences. You can find where the key is with the _Keyboard Viewer_.

Comment: @JaakL link dead

Comment: https://commitblog.eu/2016/06/22/macos-estonian-development-keyboard-layout/

Answer (score 1):

Sadly, this glaring issue still hasn't been addressed in the last 7+ years.

There is a Ukulele-based keyboard layout bundle [available on Github](https://github.com/pyyding/estonian-keyboard-mac) that's straightforward to use:

Caret is mapped to <kbd>⌥</kbd><kbd>Ä</kbd>, as is common on Windows workstations.

Backtick is unironically mapped to <kbd>`</kbd> — the key exists on the physical keyboard, the native layout just doesn't use it that way.

[image: Sample image of physical keyboard layout]

To install it:

- [download the keyboard bundle](https://github.com/pyyding/estonian-keyboard-mac) from Github
- `sudo mv ~/Downloads/EstonianDev.bundle /Library/Keyboard\ Layouts/`
- restart
- change your keyboard layout to "Estonian Dev" from Preferences → Keyboard → Input Sources → <kbd>+</kbd>.